# How do I find my old questions on here?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a couple of questions on here that I want to find, but I can't find them because I don't see any options that let me review my old questions.  Thank you

Comment: Looks like you are using a new account. If you forgot your old account name, you might be out of luck.

Comment: If you remember any specific topics or phrases from your old questions, try searching for that content.  If you remember your old account name, search for that user name.  And this question should (of course) be on meta...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/92684/lordaizen21 shows one older question asked a few days ago. Is this among the ones you are looking for? If there are questions missing, this might be because they have been deleted for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

You have two questions which have since been deleted (by yourself, it seems):

- [Please explain the unsolved 3-sat math problem as easy as possible for someone with only basic math skills](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481902/8348)
- [Does solving the P vs NP example question solve P vs NP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481923/8348)

Comment: Yeah, so far I just undeleted them because I got question banned. So it's telling me I need to fix my existing posts. I'm not sure if that will help unban me. I don't think I can vote yet, so I don't see how I can make positive contributions to get me unblocked.

Comment: @lordaizen21: [this MSO posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/214632) may be of interest to you.